# What to do with questions having good answers on another SE site?

Tags: discussion, questions, stackexchange

It happens quite often that questions are posted, which are on-topic on U&L but have good answers on another suitable Stackexchange Site (askubuntu, stackoverflow...).

I'm referring to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/596293/getting-square-boxes-instead-of-text-in-chromium-save-as-menu) which [I would consider on-topic](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389/migrate-ubuntu-specific-questions-to-askubuntu), as it may be a Gnome and not a Ubuntu issue.  It has answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224125/font-characters-displayed-as-squares-in-ubuntu-18-04) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103560/only-squares-instead-of-letters-and-numbers-are-displayed-in-my-calculator-and-o). But I rather want to know in general.

What to do with questions like this?

- [Duplicate (or let OP duplicate) the original working answer to improve U&L SE](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1391/236063) ?
- Migrate to the other SE site and mark as duplicate there ?
- Close the question as off-topic (as it suits other sites and has answers there ) ?
- ?

Comment: One more answer from a moderator suggesting to copy/adjust answers found on other (SE, in this case) sites: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2813/315749

Comment: Also here:[How do we feel about copying answers from other SE sites?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1396).

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with terdon's reference to [slm's answer](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1397/117549) here (and their [subsequent answer](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2813/117549) a year later, via fra-san)

Comment: @plumo, please let me know if you agree with closing this as a duplicate of the linked Q's

Comment: I agree. Thanks!